# How to get a 'done' message upon completion of bulk insert?

Tags: sql, sql-server, node.js

I am trying to run a function upon the completion of a bulk insert request using Node.js, the mssql library, and SQL Server:

```
sql.connect(config, function (err) {
  // error handling

  var request = new sql.Request()
  request.bulk(table, function (err, rowCount) {
    if (err) {
      // error handling
    }
  })
  request.on('error', function (err) { // Doesn't Register
    console.dir(err)
  })
  request.on('done', function (returnValue, affected) { // Doesn't Register
    MyClass.MyFunction()  // FUNCTION I NEED TO CALL
  })
})
sql.on('error', function (err) {
  // error handling
  sql.close()
})
```

Neither the error, nor the done event is triggered. I need to run `MyFunction` only after the SQL request is finished. Why is it not triggering the event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use callback on `bulk` function, as described in [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#bulk-table-callback):

```
request.bulk(table, function (err, rowCount) {
    if (err) {
        // error handling
    } else {
        MyClass.MyFunction();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [documents](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#bulktable-callback), your request will be done in the `.bulk()` callback. Not sure why the Request 'done' event isn't called, but try using the bulk callback.

```
request.bulk(table, function (err, rowCount) {
    if (err) {
      // error handling
    }
    console.log('Bulk insert is done, %s rows committed', rowCount);
  })
```

Comment: Like the other answer, this seems to have solved my problem, thank you!